# How can I pass arguments to main other than String args[] from the console?

Tags: java, arguments, program-entry-point

`main` accepts only an array of `String` (`String args[]`), and that from the console. How, then, do I pass other arguments that `main` needs? The situation is simply this: `main` calls methods that need input arguments which are objects. Could not find a way to do this. What am I missing? Interfaces maybe?

Comment: The question is , from where you got those objects to pass in :) ? Think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `main()` method is the entry point to start a Java program. If you relay on input parameters you need to represent them as strings. Use those to instantiate java objects and pass those to the methods which require them. The strings passed to `main()` may represent a path to a properties file or even a path to a spring context which to start-up. You are not really restricted. Consider the `main()` method to bootstrap your application and the string parameter to point your application to arbitrary types of more complex information if needed.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. I had the impression that what I was trying was "not done" in Java. I am new to OOP and still getting over the urge to procedural-program.

Answer (score 3):

How could you pass objects from the command line? The command line is JUST a string (and that's what gets passed to `main` - an array of `String`s).

You should construct your objects in `main` (and probably set some attributes based on command line parameters) and call the desired methods afterwards.

Comment: The `main()` method can be called as well from within a Java program, even so it is rarely done. I just want to point out, that the command line is not required or that the `main()` method is not restricted to a command line. But the design of the `main()` method is historically motivated by a command line use case.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't send anything else apart from String[] to your main() method. main() is meant to be used that way.

Answer (score 0):

You may use varargs instead of string[], like:

```
public static void main(String...args){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

(String args[])....it means main method takes only Strings as arguments from command line....Incase u want some other datatype like int or something else as arguments...u can declare them in the main method as follows...

```
Int x=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
Int y=Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
...
```

after declaring like this in main method...u can give integer values as arguments.